# Is it possible to clone the device controller for my headphones?

Tags: windows, audio, drivers

Many applications don't have their own volume sliders which means that I cannot adjust the loudness of them separately. In a situation where I have two such programs running, I would like to adjust their volumes separately because sometimes one of the programs is significantly louder than the other which makes multitasking impossible

I was thinking that a workaround to this issue might be to make a copy of the "High Definition Audio Device" controller for the same headphones that I am using. It would seem that making the two programs use different audio controllers would allow me to adjust their volumes separately as there is an option to make sound adjustments for the specific device.

Neither Device Manager nor the Sound panel have an option to do this however, so I assume that this operation would involve some sort of console command or registry tampering. Seeing as I have no experience with Windows tinkering, I do not know where to start exploring this issue.

Where is the configuration for the audio devices stored? What can I do to duplicate the controller for my headphones?

Answer (score 1):

Right click the windows volume icon in the task bar and select "volume mixer".

The volume mixer will allow you to adjust the volume per application.

[image]

Comment: Wow didn't know such a feature existed. Thank you, although I'd still interested in a bit of intro to how Windows stores its controllers anyway

Comment: I don't think that would be possible, as it would require two software drivers which normally require *exclusive* control of a hardware device to somehow understand and share access and time talking to the device. The volume mixer is the right way to do this as it happens before the drivers get involved.